# Why is IE8 giving me a Script Error?

Tags: jquery

I'm having the following error on IE8 with a script:

It says Line 77, char 3, Expected Identifier

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $carousel = $('#carousel_7').carousel({
            loop: false,
            indicator: true
        }),
        var $prev = $('#carousel_7_prev'), //This one is line 77
            var $next = $('#carousel_7_next'),
                set_state = function () {
                    var state = $carousel.carousel('getMoveState');
                    switch(state) {
                    case 'min':
                        $prev.prop('disabled', 'disabled').css({
                            'visibility': 'hidden'
                        });
                        $next.prop('disabled', '').css({
                            'visibility': 'visible'
                        });
                        break;
                    case 'max':
                        $prev.prop('disabled', '').css({
                            'visibility': 'visible',
                        });
                        $next.prop('disabled', 'disabled').css({
                            'visibility': 'hidden'
                        });
                        break;
                    case true:
                        $prev.prop('disabled', '').css({
                            'visibility': 'visible'
                        });
                        $next.prop('disabled', '').css({
                            'visibility': 'visible'
                        });
                        break;
                    default:
                        $prev.prop('disabled', 'disabled').css({
                            'visibility': 'hidden'
                        });
                        $next.prop('disabled', 'disabled').css({
                            'visibility': 'hidden'
                        });
                    }
                };
    set_state();
    $prev.on('click', function () {
        $carousel.carousel('prev');
    });
    $next.on('click', function () {
        $carousel.carousel('next');
    });
    $carousel.bind({
        'Carousel.next': function () {
            set_state();
        },
        'Carousel.prev': function () {
            set_state();
        }
    });
});
```

I already tried to add the var's but keep not working fine, the error still appearing all the time.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is line 77? In `case 'max` you have `$prev.prop('disabled', '').css({
                'visibility' : 'visible',
            });`, try it without the trailing comma. IE is very fussy

Comment: Try putting `;` instead of `,` on line 77 and 78

Comment: What is the intention of the comma? Should it not be a semicolon?

Comment: @asprin, it is an object so it can't have an `;`

Comment: @putvande I'm pretty sure it can. Aha! Yes it indeed can http://jsfiddle.net/S5ZB6/ In fact, putting a comma is breaking the code

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, tried them all but still giving me the same error.

Comment: @putvande is right, you can't replace the comma with a semicolon. That will throw a syntax error. It shouldn't have either.

Comment: @JonathanNicol Yep. I was referring to `var $prev = $('#carousel_7_prev'),` as that is marked as line 77

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is at these two lines

just change

```
var $prev = $('#carousel_7_prev'), //This one is line 77
var $next = $('#carousel_7_next'),
```

to

```
$prev = $('#carousel_7_prev'), //This one is line 77
$next = $('#carousel_7_next'),
```

The reason is that compiler is expecting an identifier but instead it saw a variable so we remove 'var' from it.